# How to disable Default Menu in CustomTabs in android?

Tags: android, webview, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I am using the 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0' in android, 
I wanted to delete the default menu item "Open In Chrome" from the menu list, because i wanted to handle the onClick of "Open In Chrome", my understanding was, we can handle onclick only if i add the menu item using "addMenuItem". Can you please guide me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment, it's not possible to hide the overflow menu or "Open in Chrome" menu item in Custom tabs.

Comment: Can we atleast remove the entire menu dialog and show our own dialog like facebook?

Comment: @Murali the only way is to self customize custom tabs library https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-provider/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/customtabsbrowser/CustomTabController.java